# Бот для консольной программы

Tags: c++

Есть консольная программа. Ее исходный код:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {

 int x;

 cin >> x;
 cout << x*2;

 return 0;
 }
```

Нужно написать другую консольную программу, которая будет запускать эту программу, вводить в неё значение и "грабить" результат. Как это реализовать ?

Comment: Ну и придумали же Вы заголовок вопроса !  Если бы не увидел @mikillskegg, никогда бы внимания  не обратил.

Теперь по делу. В принципе Вам ответили про pipes. Данная программа работать конечно будет. 

В более общем случае Вы должны учитывать буферизацию stdout в запускаемой программе и либо добавить в нее выталкивание (flush) потока вывода в необходимых местах, либо использовать вместо пайпа псевдотерминальный интерфейс.

Второй подводный камень в задачах такого типа заключается в возможной блокировке на чтении-записи в двух процессах из-за ограниченного буфера в пайпе.
(прод. след.)

Comment: (продолжение)

---

Один из приемов, позволяющих избежать блокировки это использование select() перед чтением-записью в пайп (псевдотерминал) в Вашем "боте". Вы должны **всегда** стремиться в первую очередь извлечть (read) данные из пайпа, но только если они там есть (тут нужен select()), а при записи в пайп (конечно если в нем вообще есть место) играться с таймаутом и размером блока записи.

Конечно, возможны другие приемы. Hапример несколько threads.

---

Тут все от конкретной задачи зависит. 

Удачи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для никсов делается примерно так.

В родительском приложении создаются 2 пайпа (неименованный канал) - один для передачи данных от родителю детю (№1), а другой наоборот (№2). Далее при помощи fork() запускается новый процесс. Перед заменой образа процесса exec-ом закрывается в пайп №1 конец для записи (1), а конец для чтения (0) с помощью сисвызова dup2 соединяется с fd 0. Для пайпа №2 закрывается конец 0, а конец для записи соединяется с fd 1. Далее запускается exec. В родительском процессе в пайпе №1 закрывается конец для чтения, в пайпе №2 - для записи. Теперь родитель может писать в пайп 1, а дитё будет получать эти данные через fd 0, т.е. через стандартный дескриптор ввода, и наоборот.

Для винды, как понимаю, похожий алгоритм. Там тоже есть пайпы и др.

Answer (score 1):

Можно ли разбить бота на 2 отдельные программы - одна генерирует вход, вторая читает выход?
Если да, то пишем их и запускаем в консоли чтото вроде: 
path/to/bin/BOT_Generator | path/to/bin/MyProgram | path/to/bin/BOT_Reader     (это для Unix-систем, хз как правильно в Windows)

если нет, то кажется чтото похожее функционал есть в Qt QProcess. Там чтото вроде signal void canReadOutput();
 и
 slot void writeToInput();